# jQuery UI - how to check if a draggable item snaps

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

I'm having issues with a jQuery UI condition.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable2").draggable({ 
        snap: ".ui-widget-header",
        snapMode: "inner", 
        revert: true
    });
});
```

My question:

How do I use an *if statement* so my draggable item does **NOT** revert if it snaps to my *ui-widget-header*?

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: *if* snaps or *when* it snaps. These are two very different concepts.

Comment: i have an array, so i want that if my item is snapped on his four borders it doesn't revert :) sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI does keep an internal "state" of "snapped" elements, but you have to work a little to get at it.

You're going to want to define an event handler for the stop event (which is called when a draggable object is stopped dragging).

An array called snapElements is maintained inside the widget data, and it looks something like this:

```
[ 
    { 
        height: 102, 
        item: { /* DOM element */ }, 
        left: 10, 
        snapping: false, 
        top: 10, 
        width: 102 
    }, ...
]
```

What you are really looking for here is the `snapping` property. snapping will tell you if the item is currently "`snapping`" to a draggable object.

The `snapElements` array is updated for every `drag` event, so it is always up-to-date in `drag` handlers. From there, we only have to obtain the `draggable` widget instance from the associated element with data().

With this array in mind, we can write code like this to determine wither it snapped to the target or not:

```
$("#draggable2").draggable({
    snap: ".ui-widget-header",
    snapMode: "inner", 
    revert: true
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var draggable = $(this).data("draggable");
        $.each(draggable.snapElements, function(index, element) {
            if (element.snapping) {
                //i can't quit figure out how to stop the reverting from here, but here's you condition.
                console.log("Snapped !!");
            }
        });
    },
});
```

oh, and i found this online hope it's helpfull.
[Revert Function callback.](http://agilepro.com/mod_geek/javascript/jquery-ui-draggable-revert-callback/)